# Local Notification when date is set on a UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, usernotifications

I want to set up a local notification when a user sets a date on a `UIPicker`.

At the moment I have no code because I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want the user to choose when to send the notification, so:

First, authorise for notifications in the app delegate, like so:

```
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Next, assuming you've created a datePicker and connected it to the code:

```
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
```

Your function for scheduling the notification is:

```
func scheduleNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent() //The notification's content
    content.title = "Hi there"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let dateComponent = datePicker.calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: datePicker.date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponent, repeats: false)

    let notificationReq = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationReq, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

You can read more about UserNotifications and Notification Triggers here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Comment: Thank you, so it I just have a picker that just has the date and month i will have to change .day, .hour, .minute to .day .month?

Comment: Yes, you should. If my answer is correct, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Is there an error?  If not, maybe you should put option for hour and minutes.

Comment: Nope no error, i have also added back hour and minutes to see if it worked. I have also put scheduleNotification() inside of a button.

Comment: Did you authorise for notifications?

Comment: It's happening to everyone. Great!

Comment: Another quick question if that is okay. I have set the picker with just day and month. The user can then set if they want the notification 3 hours, 1 day, 1 week etc before the notification goes off at midnight. 
For example they want it to go off on the 9th October but they set it 3 hours before so the notification goes off at 9pm on the 8th October.
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Didn't really got it...but what is the question?

Comment: sorry forgot that haha, how would I set this up?

Comment: You should use unique identifiers when scheduling your notifications. You can use trigger.nextTriggerDate() description as the identifier